# How to back fillna only one na value with a specific value

Tags: python, pandas

I want to back fillna, but I only want to backfill only one na value and replace that value with a specific value (1)

I tried using

```
df.fillna(value=1,method='bfill',inplace=True,limit=1)
```

but I get

```
ValueError: Cannot specify both 'value' and 'method'.
```

because I cannot use method and value at the same time. If this was possible, I would not be asking this question (pandas possibly should look into this with a new update)

Here is an example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

col1 = [3,2,2,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,2,6,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,6]
col2 = [8,2,np.nan,np.nan,6,0,np.nan,5,np.nan,6,6,3]
col3 = [np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,6,7,np.nan,1,np.nan,np.nan,3,4]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[col1,col2,col3],columns=['col1','col2','col3'])

print(df)

index     col1     col2     col3
0          3        8       np.nan
1          2        2       np.nan
2          2        np.nan  np.nan
3          np.nan   np.nan  np.nan
4          np.nan   6       6
5          np.nan   0       7
6          2        np.nan  np.nan
7          6        5       1
8          np.nan   np.nan  np.nan
9          np.nan   6       np.nan
10         np.nan   6       3
11         6        3       4
```

here is my desired output:

```
index     col1     col2     col3
0          3        8       np.nan
1          2        2       np.nan
2          2        np.nan  np.nan
3          np.nan   1       1
4          np.nan   6       6
5          1        0       7
6          2        1       1
7          6        5       1
8          np.nan   1       np.nan
9          np.nan   6       1
10         1        6       3
11         6        3       4
```

I've been at this for hours. Anything is appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

You can `bfill` with limit 1, doesnt matter which value. Then you check which value is filled, but is still `NaN` in your original dataframe. Those indices you fill in `1`:

```
d = df.bfill(limit=1)
mask = df.isna() & d.notna()

df = pd.DataFrame(np.where(mask, 1, df), columns=df.columns)
```

**Output**

```
    col1  col2  col3
0    3.0   8.0   NaN
1    2.0   2.0   NaN
2    2.0   NaN   NaN
3    NaN   1.0   1.0
4    NaN   6.0   6.0
5    1.0   0.0   7.0
6    2.0   1.0   1.0
7    6.0   5.0   1.0
8    NaN   1.0   NaN
9    NaN   6.0   1.0
10   1.0   6.0   3.0
11   6.0   3.0   4.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Apparently `ffill` cannot handle specifying both `value` and `method`. Here's an alternative approach:

```
m = (df.isna() & df.shift(-1).notna()).shift().fillna(False)
pd.DataFrame(np.where(m, 1, df), columns=df.columns)

     col1  col2  col3
0    3.0   8.0   NaN
1    2.0   2.0   NaN
2    2.0   NaN   NaN
3    NaN   1.0   1.0
4    NaN   6.0   6.0
5    1.0   0.0   7.0
6    2.0   5.0   1.0
7    6.0   5.0   1.0
8    NaN   6.0   NaN
9    NaN   6.0   1.0
10   1.0   6.0   3.0
11   6.0   3.0   4.0
```